# Include Javascript Module in Wordpress plugin - The right way

Tags: php, wordpress

To add js-cookie (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) into my Wordpress plugin I´m using this code:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'drsm_import_cookies_plugin');
if (!function_exists('drsm_import_cookies_plugin')) {
    function drsm_import_cookies_plugin() {
        echo '<script type="module">import * as Cookies from "'.plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__)).'vendor/js/js.cookie.min.js"</script>';
    }
}
```

**The wordpress review team says:**

> Why is the code being included like that? It's an odd usage of script modules.

What would be a better way to import this script with module into my Wordpress plugin?

Comment: Why as a module import in the first place, considering that not even all browsers are supporting that yet? I’d use the UMD variant and `wp_register_script`/`wp_enqueue_script` here. Then this doesn’t have to use the rather ugly (IMHO) `wp_print_scripts` hook to begin with either.

Comment: But how can I use the `Cookies` variable then? If I import only the file I get the error `Cookies is undefined` ...

Comment: Where are you trying to access it? Sounds like it might simply be a problem with source code order …?

Comment: It was my fault. It works now. Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try this.

paste this code into your wp plugin file

```
function drsm_import_cookies_plugin() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', plugin_dir_url(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/vendor/js/js.cookie.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'drsm_import_cookies_plugin' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Thanks.

Comment: But how can I use the `Cookies` variable then? If I import only the file I get the error `Cookies is undefined` ...

Comment: This adds the JavaScript as script while he wants it to be `type="module"`